# Standardized Constructors Across Subclasses?

Tags: java, abstract-class

I have an abstract class `AbstractClass`, and two non-abstract classes that extend it: `A` and `B`. Both `A` and `B` have constructors that take in a `String` argument. I also have a method that takes in `Class<? extends AbstractClass>` and then creates a new instance of it. How can I make it so that all of children of `AbstractClass` have a `String` in their constructor?

Code in case I wasn't very clear in the explanation:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
    // do stuff
}

public class A extends AbstractClass {
    public A(String str) {
        // do stuff
    }
}

public class B extends AbstractClass {
    public B(String str) {
        // do stuff
    }
}

// this is stuff in other places
public void instantiateClass(Class<? extends AbstractClass> obj) {
    AbstractClass object = obj.newInstance("blah"); // Error: Expected 0 arguments but found 1
    // do stuff
}
instantiateClass(A.class);
instantiateClass(B.class);
```

Comment: You can't. There is no way to require it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. There is no way to require a constructor to have any arguments.

However, you pass a `Function<? super String, ? extends AbstractClass>` instead of a `Class<? extends AbstractClass>`: that way, you have to supply a thing which will accept a single `String` parameter, even if that's not specifically a constructor:

```
public void instantiateClass(Function<? super String, ? extends AbstractClass> fn) {
    AbstractClass object = fn.apply("blah");
    // do stuff
}

instantiateClass(A::new);
instantiateClass(B::new);
```

and if you have a class whose constructor doesn't take a single `String` parameter:

```
public class C extends AbstractClass {
    public C() {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

then `instantiateClass(C::new)` wouldn't compile; but `instantiateClass(unused -> new C())` would.

Comment: This approach also helps reduce the amount of reflection boilerplate, as you can just say `A::new` without checked exceptions.

Comment: It's also checked at compile time, not runtime.